# What is purpose of App in Userpool in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am new to AWS Cognito. Based on description,  Userpool is used for authentication.  If I am a user in the userpool, I can use this user name and password to authenticate my identity.  Why do I need to add App to userpool?

Thanks for help in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Cognito allows you to create a number of apps to integrate with your user pool. On each app, you can custom the Authentication flow, Access/Refresh token expiration, attribute read and write permissions, hostUI...

Use case: you use the same user pool for both apps but there are some custom like:

- App A: just allow authentication via the ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH and access token expiration is 5 minutes.
- App B: just allow authentication via the ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH and access token expiration is 30 minutes.

Hope that's clear.